# Docker for Mac(Edge) - Kubernetes - LoadBalancer

Tags: docker-for-mac

It is so cool that we have a LoadBalancer in Docker for Mac.

I have a question regarding ports created:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    run: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    port: 9999
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This gives me(kubectl get service):

```
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.96.128.253   localhost     9999:32455/TCP   2s
```

What is `32455`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

32455 is your nodePort.  Kubernetes automatically assigns a unique nodePort for any service that is accessible outside of a cluster (including services of type LoadBalancer.  You can specify these yourself as well in the same config, as long as you .

With regards to Docker for Mac specifically, Kubernetes is creating a service which is listening on localhost:9999.  This is an "egress" that kubernetes is creating since you don't actually have a load balancer, it's essentially simulating one.  Beyond the "load balancer/egress", it still behaves just like it would in production - that is Kubernes assigns a nodePort for the service.  You `curl localhost:32455`, you will likely get the same response as if you had `curl localhost:9999`.

Comment: Ok, so it goes like: 9999 >> 32455 >>> 80? Is that in a table somewhere? It does not work to call localhost:32455, but that can just be a Docker thing.

Comment: Yes, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ . The most helpful part for you is probably https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types . but I would recommend reading the whole page.  Probably a 30-60 minute read, but you will have kubernetes services mastered.