# helm sentry created additional load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-helm, sentry

I using Kubernetes on Digitalocean and I have installed nginx-ingress which created an external load balancer. However when I install Sentry using helm https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sentry another load balancer was created. Oddly though sentry is only accessible through the nginx load balancer, i.e if I point my domain to the ip address of the load balancer created in the Sentry install it does load.

I new to kubernetes so pretty sure I've done something wrong when 
installing Sentry and assume it will relate to the values I used when installing the chart as it has a Service type of LoadBalancer.

So my question is can I get rid of the loadbalancer created by Sentry and what's the best way to do it with breaking anything.

```
# Name of the service and what port to expose on the pod
# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
service:
  name: sentry
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalPort: 9000
  internalPort: 9000
  ## External IP addresses of service
  ## Default: nil
  ##
  # externalIPs:
  # - 192.168.0.1

## Configure ingress resource that allow you to access the
## Sentry installation. Set up the URL
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/
##
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: sentry.mydomain.com

  ## Ingress annotations
  ##
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

  ## Ingress TLS configuration
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace
  ##
  tls:
    - secretName: sentry-mydomain-crt
      hosts:
        - sentry.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can set the type of the service in the values file to ClusterIP.

The values file inside the chart defaults to LoadBalancer type (https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/sentry/values.yaml) but you can override this by setting it to ClusterIP in your values file that you deploy with or by using '--set service.type=ClusterIP' as a parameter.

Then it will only be exposed through the Ingress and won't have an external LoadBalancer. See [Ingress service type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959974/ingress-service-type)

Since you've already installed sentry you will want to find its release name (you'll see it as a prefix on the sentry resources from 'kubectl get' commands like 'kubectl get pod' or from 'helm list'). If you are using it then you'll want to do a 'helm upgrade'. If you aren't using it yet then you could do 'helm delete' on that release and install it again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ClusterIP [service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) instead of a LoadBalancer one:

```
service:
  name: sentry
  type: ClusterIP
```